# Terraform Azure provider - How do I add via terraform more than one key and/or secret for my key vault?

Tags: azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure, secret-key

All the examples I saw provide 1 key and or q secret.
Is there a way to add another one (or more)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add multiple keys or secrets for your key vault, you just need to add the resources `azurerm_key_vault_key` and `azurerm_key_vault_secret` multiple times.

It's recommended to create such resources in the loop. Terraform offers several different looping constructs, each intended to be used in a slightly different scenario:

- `count` parameter: loop over resources.
- `for_each` expressions: loop over resources and inline blocks within a resource.
- `for` expressions: loop over lists and maps.

For example, create one or more keys and secrets with `count` parameters.

```
variable "key_lists" {
    type = list(string)
    default = ["key1","key2","key3"]
    
}

variable "secret_maps" {
    type = map(string)
    default = {
        "name1"= "value1"
        "aaa" = "111"
        "bbb" = "222"
    }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "generated" {
  count        = length(var.key_lists)
  name         = var.key_lists[count.index]
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  key_type     = "RSA"
  key_size     = 2048

  key_opts = [
    "decrypt",
    "encrypt",
    "sign",
    "unwrapKey",
    "verify",
    "wrapKey",
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "example" {
  count = length(var.secret_maps)
  name         = keys(var.secret_maps)[count.index]
  value        = values(var.secret_maps)[count.index]
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id

}
```

You could read [this blog](https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9) for more Terraform loop tips.

Comment: Now, I'm getting the following error, regarding
resource "azurerm_disk_encryption_set" "example" {
  name                = "example-set"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.example.name}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.example.location}"
  key_vault_key_id    = "${azurerm_key_vault_key.example.id}"

Incorrect attribute value type
 on main.tf line 116, in resource "azurerm_disk_encryption_set" "example":
116:   key_vault_key_id    = "${azurerm_key_vault_key.example[count.index]}"
Inappropriate value for attribute "key_vault_key_id": string required.

Comment: Do you want one of keys to encrypt the disk? Try to use `key_vault_key_id    = azurerm_key_vault_key.example[count.index].id` or `key_vault_key_id    = azurerm_key_vault_key.example[0].id`?

Comment: key_vault_key_id    = "${azurerm_key_vault_key.example[0].id}" looks good. Thanks.